# Simulator architectures - Cordova plugin that contains a native iOS framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am building an iOS cordova plugin which contains a native iOS framework inside.

If I compile the framework with only devices architectures, I cannot build the iOS project because of the missing simulator architectures. I have checked with *'lipo'* other plugins and they contain both the simulator and devices architectures.

I was able to compile a fat framework including all architectures, but I know that AppStore rejects apps containing simulator architectures.

So how **can I distribute the cordova plugin to be tested both on devices and simulators and can pass inspection**? In other words, **is there a way to strip the simulator architectures from a fat framework in a way that is transparent to the user of the plugin?**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help :-

I had the same problem working with the third party API , After trying many solution's I ended up the with the dependency tool called [COCOAPODS](https://cocoapods.org/) that will manage third parties api's for you .

Comment: could you elaborate, please? We're searching for any kind of steps on how to strip simulator architectures out of a fat framework included in a cordova plugin for release. Couldn't find anything relevant on google.

Comment: I don't know much about your situation because I'm also a beginner   but i had the similar problem when i was working with the mikmidi framework , my app was running successfully on iphone but not on simulator, saying that the framework's architecture  is not built for the simulator (because i didn't use the right way to include the framework into the project ) than i ended up using cocoa-pods to add the framework into project and everything works fine after that.